# Whats wrong with my php login page?

Tags: php

Ok so I get this error when i try to login:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: numrows in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\login.php on line 14
```

That user doesn't exist.
Do you notice any errors right away trying to learn PHP and MySQL. Here is the code

INDEX PHP PAGE

```
<html>
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br />
        <input type="submit" name="Login In"><br />
    </form>
</html>
```

PHP LOGIN PAGE

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username&&$password)
{
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Couldn't Connect!");
    mysql_select_db("phplogin") or die("Couldn't Find DB!");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='username'");

    $numrow = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if ($numrows!=0)
    {
        // code to login
    }
    else
        die("That user doesn't exist");

}
else
    die("Please enter and username and password!");
?>
```

Comment: _Whats wrong with my php login page?_ your query is open to [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if ($numrows!=0)` should be `if ($numrow!=0)`

and you  forgot a $ in your query:

`$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."'");`

Comment: or change `$numrow =` to `$numrows =` (I would opt for $numrows)!

Comment: Ok so that got rid of the error message but now when i login with the user i made in phpmyadmin it says that user does not exist

Comment: Thanks so much know this was a noob question but just learning :)

Comment: Np. You also should add a mysql_error() to your code to see what was wrong. But please only for the coding process. So f.e.: `$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Couldn't Connect!".mysql_error());`